# How to fix '$.extend is not a function' error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, toastr

I have SPAs. I use nodejs + mongoDb. In the end of my SPAs, I have contact form. When visitor fill the contact form and click submit button. I received an E-mail. Everythings fine until here. I want to show notification for visitor. and I decided to use toastr. When I click submit button. I getting an error. "$.extend is not a function".

In npm web site, toastr say before the toastr.js include jquery. I include jquery. but nothing I getting same error.

app.js call trycontroller.

```
tryController(app);
```

tryContoller

```
// I installed jquery from npm 

const jquery = require('jquery');
const toastr = require('toastr');

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        main(req.body.nameContact, req.body.emailContact, req.body.subjectContact, req.body.messageContact)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Email Sended");  

                toastr.success('Have fun storming the castle!', 'Miracle Max Says')

                res.redirect('#contactForm');
            }, err => { 

                console.log("Email Error: " + err) })
            .catch(console.error);
    });
```

and this my index.ejs

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this because I am having the same problem?

Comment: Hi, I didint fix this problem. I tried many things but I couldnt solve. if I find any solution. I will write here.